# build_* not working despite being has_one

Tags: ruby-on-rails

My intention here is just to create a corresponding contact when a user
signs up, but the said contact is never created, despite using build_*
with a has_one:

Contact model:

```
has_one :user
```

User model:

```
belongs_to :contact
```

Users Controller:

```
def signup
  @user = User.new
end

def signup_success
 @user = User.find params[:id]
 contact = @user.build_contact
 contact.contactable = School.first
 contact.save
end

protected
```

routes:

```
map.resources :users,
:collection => {
  :signup => :get
},
:member => {
  :signup_success => :any
}
```

Any idea of what I'm doing wrong? Thanks for any suggestions.

Comment: What errors does the contact object have when you try to save it in the console? `contact.errors.full_messages`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Does it work if you pass the attributes to `build`?

```
contact = @user.build_contact(:contactable => School.first)  
contact.save
```

Comment: No. Even when I add it directly to the model, it still doesn't work:

before_create :ensure_site 

    def ensure_site
      if :signup
          contact = self.build_contact(:contactable => School.first)  
          contact.save
        end
      end

Comment: The issue was when I save a contact, it was invoking a validate from the contacts page which was preventing the saving. Thanks though. I like your parameter hash technique better than the multi-step way I was doing it.